# Unable to get DatePicker select the current date (ANDROID), Keeping previous month Enabled

Tags: android, datepicker

I managed to get date picker with only previous month visible, but my cursor is by default selecting the previous month date, can some one help me in with this issue....I want previous month visible with cursor selecting current date on open.

**Kindly help and Thankyou in Advance....**

Here is my Code

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {


    ListView lstv22;
    ArrayList<AshTable2> array222;

    EditText inputSearch1;
    CustomListViewAdapter2 adapter2;

    int day1, month1, year1;

    private int mYearIni, mMonthIni, mDayIni, sYearIni, sMonthIni, sDayIni, mYearIni1, mMonthIni1, mDayIni1, sYearIni2, sMonthIni2, sDayIni2, mYearIni3, mMonthIni3, mDayIni3;

    Calendar C = Calendar.getInstance();

    TextView noSearch;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_fragment,
                container, false);


//        sMonthIni = C.get(Calendar.MONTH);
//        sDayIni = C.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//        sYearIni = C.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        getActivity().setTitle("Search");
        array222 = new ArrayList<>();

        lstv22 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lst_vw2);

        inputSearch1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch1);

        noSearch = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noSearch);


        inputSearch1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String text = inputSearch1.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter2.filter(text);
                listCheck();


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {

            }

        });

        adapter2 = new CustomListViewAdapter2(getActivity(), R.layout.home_list_view, array222);


        lstv22.setAdapter(adapter2);


        inputSearch1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputSearch1.getWindowToken(), 0);

//                final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//                mYearIni=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
//                mMonthIni=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
//                mDayIni=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                showDispatchCalendar();

            }
        });


        return view;


    }



    private void showDispatchCalendar() {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog da = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mDateSetListener, mYearIni, mMonthIni, mDayIni);
        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
//        long currentTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime();
//        Date newDate = new Date(currentTime - 29 * 24 * 3600 * 1000);

        da.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime());
        da.show();

//        long newDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
//        da.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate);
//        da.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate);

        da.show();

    }


    private void colocar_fecha() {

        day1 = mDayIni;
        month1 = mMonthIni + 1;
        year1 = mYearIni;
        inputSearch1.setText(day1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + year1 + " ");
    }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    mYearIni = year;
                    mMonthIni = monthOfYear;
                    mDayIni = dayOfMonth;

                    colocar_fecha();
                }
            };




    public void listCheck() {

        if (adapter2.getCount() != 0) {
            noSearch.setText(" ");
        } else {

            noSearch.setText(" No Search Result Found ");

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: means you want to set current Date whenever you open DatePicker...???

Comment: Yes with previous month Enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
long currentTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime();
Date newDate = new Date(currentTime - 29 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); //Subtract 30 days
```

set this date in your code..

```
da.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime());
da.show();
```

Hope it will help you, Check & let me kno

Edited

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dd = new DatePickerDialog(activity,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    try {
                        // Do your stuff
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }
                }
            }, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
dd.show();
```

Comment: i get what your saying... but what is currentTime ?

Comment: i get an Error for [ (currentTime - 29 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); ]

 saying - getTime() in Calander cannot be applied to ( long )

Comment: Oops, Tat code is working fine for me.. can you post your complete code ?

Comment: well now it shows 26-4-2017 as current date with previous dates disabled.

i want todays to be current date, with previous month dates also enabled.

Comment: If u need current date, you can use like this `da.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime());`

Comment: BRO, i want current date selected, but keeping previous month dates Enabled.

Right now current date is selected, but previous dates are disabled

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the `showDispatchCalendar()` add this...

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYearIni=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonthIni=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDayIni=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create DatePicker class as below :

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondateSet;
private int year, month, day;

public DatePickerFragment() {}

public void setCallBack(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate) {
    ondateSet = ondate;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    super.setArguments(args);
    year = args.getInt("year");
    month = args.getInt("month");
    day = args.getInt("day");
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, ondateSet, year, month, day);
}
```

}

Then use it in any class as :

```
private void showDatePicker() {
    DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();
    /**
     * Set Up Current Date Into dialog
     */
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    date.setArguments(args);
    /**
     * Set Call back to capture selected date
     */
    date.setCallBack(ondate1);

    date.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
}

public String checkDigit(int number) {
    return number <= 9 ? "0" + number : String.valueOf(number);
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {

        etDob.setText(String.valueOf(checkDigit(dayOfMonth)) + "/" + String.valueOf(checkDigit(monthOfYear + 1))
                + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
    }
};
```

This way you will always get current date.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            Log.e("DialogMonth", ""+month);
```